# Using MySQL++ throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I'm attempting to connect to a MySQL database with the following code. But it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS as soon as it gets to the "Query query = conn.query()" line. What could be the reason? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>

using namespace mysqlpp;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    try {
        Connection conn(false);
        if (conn.connect("db", "localhost", "root", "root")) {
            Query query = conn.query("select * from django_site");
        }
    }
    catch (BadQuery er) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << er.what();
        return -1;
    } catch (const BadConversion& er) {
        // Handle bad conversions
        std::cerr << "Conversion error: " << er.what() << std::endl <<
        "\tretrieved data size: " << er.retrieved <<
        ", actual size: " << er.actual_size << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (const Exception& er) {
        // Catch-all for any other MySQL++ exceptions
        std::cerr << "Error: " << er.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Printing the conn object returns

```
(mysqlpp::Connection) conn = {
  mysqlpp::OptionalExceptions = {
    exceptions_ = false
  }
  error_message_ = "\xe5$}\xff\x7f"
  driver_ = 0x00007fff5fc005a8
  co
```

What's more troubling is that the "conn_" variable is pointing to NULL

```
(mysqlpp::Query) query = {
  std::__1::ostream = {
    std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > = {
      std::__1::ios_base = {
        __fmtflags_ = 0
        __precision_ = 0
        __width_ = 0
        __rdstate_ = 0
        __exceptions_ = 0
        __rdbuf_ = 0x0000000000000000
        __loc_ = 0x0000000000000000
        __fn_ = 0x0000000000000000
        __index_ = 0x0000000000000000
        __event_size_ = 0
        __event_cap_ = 0
        __iarray_ = 0x0000000000000000
        __iarray_size_ = 0
        __iarray_cap_ = 0
        __parray_ = 0x0000000000000000
        __parray_size_ = 0
        __parray_cap_ = 0
      }
      __tie_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __fill_ = 0
    }
  }
  mysqlpp::OptionalExceptions = {
    exceptions_ = false
  }
  template_defaults = {
    std::__1::vector<mysqlpp::SQLTypeAdapter, std::__1::allocator<mysqlpp::SQLTypeAdapter> > = size=0 {}
    parent_ = 0x0000000000000000
    processing_ = false
  }
  conn_ = 0x0000000000000000
  copacetic_ = false
  parse_elems_ = size=0 {}
  parsed_names_ = size=0 {}
  parsed_nums_ = size=0 {}
  sbuffer_ = {
    std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > = {
      __loc_ = {
        __locale_ = 0x0000000000000000
      }
      __binp_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __ninp_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __einp_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __bout_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __nout_ = 0x0000000000000000
      __eout_ = 0x0000000000000000
    }
    __str_ = ""
    __hm_ = 0x0000000000000000
    __mode_ = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Never see this lib before, but I'm guessing it's because you're calling .query() with no arguments... e.g. sending a null query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've posted back sooner. For others who ran into the same issue, the reason for the error is quite silly on my end. Turns out that I'm using C++11's std library, but MySQL++ wasn't originally compiled against it. Recompiling MySQL++ with the newer std lib fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the return type of the call to connect() before you create a query. Calling

```
Query query = conn.query();
```

if connect() fails will likely be the cause of this exception.

According to the manual pages http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1Query.html passing a NULL `char*` to the `Connection::query()` function is valid as this is the default argument so I would assume that your database connection request has failed. I would check the return type of

```
conn.connect("db", "localhost", "root", "root");
```

and double check your database name, user name and password strings that you are passing to this function.

Also, check that your application has the required permissions to be connecting to the database as `root`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the conn part to ___if (conn.connect("db", "localhost", "root", "root")) { Query query = conn.query("select * from django_site"); }____; it's still not working... But "mysql --host =localhost --user=root --password=root db" connects just fine in the command line prompt.

Comment: @haginile So does the code version of the call to connect fail? If so, does your executable have sufficient permissions to try to connect as root user?

Comment: Sorry i'm a complete newbie here.. I tried creating a new user and granted all permissions (CREATE USER 'xcode'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xcode'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'xcode'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;), but it still fails. Anything else I need to do? Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried running your application as the super user/administrator ?

Comment: Hi @mathematician1975. I don't think it's a connection issue.. After issuing conn.connect, _conn.connected()_ returns true now, but conn.query() still throws the same error...